# Encrypted & unencrypted connection strings in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, web-config

Is it possible to have both encypted and unencrypted connection strings in the same web.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that you can encrypt an individual connection string as part of the ConnectionStrings section.  This is because ConfigurationElement objects (ConnectionStringSetting derives from) has an ElementInformation Property which does not have a Protect method.  A ConfigurationSection has a SectionInformation Property which does have a Protect method, ConnectionStringsSection inherits from ConfigurationSection.

So, with that said, you can encrypt a ConnectionStringsSection, but not a ConnectionStringSetting.

However, all is not lost.  You do have the ability to create your sections/elements to maintain your non-encrypted (or encrytped depending on which way you want to go) connection strings.  You just won't be able access them using the WebConfigurationManager's ConnectionStrings Property.